# Find 2 cells, based on 3 inputs with VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

Like the title, I should find 2 cells based on 3 inputs that are:

1) Month (January, February, March ecc..) 
2) Initial Number: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) 
3) Final Number: (5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10)

To be clear I post also my Excel file below:

[image: Excel File]

So like in the IMG, how to find the Rows **N5** AND **T5**, given the input (February, 2, 8)?

This is what I tried but it's not working correctly

```
Set Found = ws.Range("C5:V5").Find(ComboBox1.Value) ' February

With ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Column, ComboBox2.Value), ws.Cells(Found.Row, ComboBox3.Value))
    .Clear
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
End With
```

Thanks and good day

Comment: What's "not working" can you post an example of data (not the full workbook) and what is "not happening"  If there are errors what they are etc.  Thanks

Comment: @Nathan_Sav It's not giving me errors, I just can't find the Cells I need. In **Found.Column = 13** and **ComboBox2.Value = 2** so final result **Cell(13, 2)** that is **M2** and its incorrect. Hope I was clear. Regards

Comment: Use `MATCH` rather than find.  `MATCH("February",rows("6:6"),0)` then resize the range and do the same wiht both the 1st and 2nd value on that range.

Comment: Merged cells don't really exist in VBA. Your value february is in cell M5, as merged cells values are in the leftmost topmost cell in the merged range. Use the resize as per @Nathan_Sav above

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm newbie and didn't know the existence of `MATCH`, but also what does resize means? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Why not just calculate it? If it's 10 numbers per month and January is the first then it's `10 x (monthnumber -1) + initial number` which is the first you are looking for

Comment: @TheMite there is help within Excel, to explain both match and resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like so.  My months are in row 8 and the other numbers in row 9.

This can be simplified once you grasp it.

```
Sub testing5()


Dim lColMth As Long
Dim rYear As Range
Dim lFirstNum As Long
Dim lSecondNum As Long
Dim rOutput As Range

lColMth = WorksheetFunction.Match("February", Rows(8), 0)

Set rYear = Cells(9, lColMth).Resize(1, 12)

lFirstNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(3, rYear, 0) + lColMth - 1
lSecondNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(9, rYear, 0) + lColMth - 1

Set rOutput = Range(Cells(9, lFirstNum), Cells(9, lSecondNum))
rOutput.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that is super complicated for me. Can I ask you some comments please? Thank you @Nathan_Sav

Comment: Use the help in VBA and google to explain it, there is only really 1 line of code, just different criteria.  You look to have only given it <3minutes of your time, try a bit longer.

Comment: I finally made it, and the start was looking like scary, but reading better makes it really more easy. Nathan you were a great teacher!

Comment: @TheMite not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will help you achieve your desired result, assuming that there are only 10 numbers below each month name:

```
Sub FindCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required

Set Found = ws.Range("C4:V4").Find(ComboBox1.Value) ' February
'find value from ComboBox1 on Range C4:V4

Set FoundInitial = ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Row + 1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(Found.Row + 1, Found.Column + 9)).Find(ComboBox2.Value)
'find ComboBox2 value on range below the Month range, assuming there are only 10 numbers per month
Set FoundFinal = ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Row + 1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(Found.Row + 1, Found.Column + 9)).Find(ComboBox3.Value)
'find ComboBox3 value on range below the Month range, assuming there are only 10 numbers per month

With ws.Range(FoundInitial.Address & ":" & FoundFinal.Address)
    .Clear
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
End With
End Sub
```